# how to fix sql server page level corruption?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-administration

How can i fix the page level corruption in sql database. I am facing a big issue related to this. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to SQL Server Management Studio

   - Select the DB
   - Right Click the DB
   - Go to Properties
   - Select Options
   - Under Other Option select the Page Verify
   - Select as NONE.
2. Run this Query to Change DB into Single User Mode

   - ALTER DATABASE corrupted_db SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
3. Run this Query to Recover the Table/DB.

   - DBCC CheckTable ('corrupted_table', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)

(OR)

- DBCC CheckDB ('corrupted_db', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)

  4. Once this Execution Completed Sql returns “Errors are Corrected”
  5. Run this Query to Change the DB into Multi-User Mode
- ALTER DATABASE Application Manager SET MULTI_USER

  6. Go to SQL Server Management Studio
- Select the DB
- Right Click the DB
- Go to Properties
- Select Options
- Under Other Option select the Page Verify
- Select the Option CHECKSUM.

  7. Now Run DBCC CHECKDB('Your DB')

Comment: thanks for your solution.

Comment: Please mark as ACCEPTED

Comment: Running the `DBCC CHECKDB REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` command might require deleting some database pages, resulting in loss of data. Also, DBCC CHECKDB commands might fail and return an error when dealing with severely corrupt SQL database files. Use third party software to repair severely corrupt MS SQL database and restore all its components, while maintaining database integrity.